# For what values of $h$ is $\mathbf{v_3}$ in the span of $\{\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_2}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

For what values of $h$ is $\mathbf{v_3}$ in the span of $\{\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_2}\}$ ? For what values of $h$ is $\{\mathbf{v_1,v_2,v_3}\}$ linearly dependent?

$\mathbf{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\
-5\\
-3\end{bmatrix},\mathbf{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\
10\\
6\end{bmatrix},\mathbf{v_3}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\
-10\\
h\end{bmatrix}$

My reasoning for the first part is as follows:

If $\mathbf{v_3}$ is in the span of $\{\mathbf{v_1,v_2}\}$ then it is a linear combination of $\mathbf{v_1,v_2}$. Writing an augmented matrix we have $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&2\\
-5&10&-10\\
-3&6&h\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&2\\
0&0&h+6\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then this system is consistent only for $h=-6$, so $\mathbf{v_3}$ is in the span of $\{\mathbf{v_1,v_2}\}$ for $h=-6$.

For the second part, we just observe that $\mathbf{v_1}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{v_2}$ and therefore $\{\mathbf{v_1,v_2,v_3}\}$ must be linearly dependent for all values of $h$.

Is my reasoning here correct? I'm fairly confident with what I have but it seems to contradict the answer given in the text. Just looking for solution verification here. Thanks!

Comment: what is the answer in the text?

Comment: "all $h$". I suspect maybe a typo?

Comment: It isn't a typo. As you observed, the two first vectors are already dependent so any vector added to them will not change this fact. Hence "all $h$". That's your answer too, isn't it?

Comment: Right. So my reasoning is correct in the first part as well then? Only for $h=-6$?

Comment: Yes, there is only one $h$ for which $v_3$ is proportional to $v_2$, and that is $h=-6$.

Comment: @Gteal Looks right to me. If $h=-6$, then $\vec{v_3}=-\vec{v_2}$ and $\vec{v_3}=2\vec{v_1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part one, note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent.  They are multiples of each other.  Thus we easily get that $v_3$ must be a multiple of $v_1$, and thus $h=-6$.  Thus there was a typo.

For part two, let's use an alternate method and see if the answers agree.  Compute the determinant.  Get $10h+60+2(-5h-30)+2(0)=0$.  This indicates that any $h$ gives you a linearly dependent set.  Of course, this is obvious, by the first observation.